# Can't detach thread forever c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, forever, detach

I am trying to detach the thread in the c++ program below so that even after the proccess terminates the thread will continue to write some characters into the text file. 
The problem is that I couln't get it done:
when the program terminates the thread stops writing into the "file.txt" file. Could you he help me with that or is this not possible at all?

```
#include<thread>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void printToFile()
{
    FILE *file;

    for (int i = 0; true; i++)
    {
        fopen_s(&file, "file.txt", "w");
        fprintf(file, "%s%d", "n: ",i);
        fclose(file);
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    thread t(printToFile);
    t.detach();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When your "main" thread terminates, all it's "child threads" are also killed. What you want is to `fork()` a separate process to do this writing to file.

Comment: As fopen_s kind of indicates he is using VS, he probably wants CreateProcess(), as Windows doesn't have a fork() call.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  `detach` only separates the thread from its parent thread, so the parent thread doesn't need to worry about cleaning it up.  Once a process dies, so does all of its threads.